# Management error message of validation rules

Tags: salesforcedx

Validation rules displays error message to the user.

I'm going to make so many objects, so I need to simplify its error message.

If I can use formula or processAutomation?

In order to user-friendly message, I want a message not like `may contains prohibited strings` but like `** is prohibited string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, dynamic error message is not available in Salesforce.

Refer to this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IEYh